# AngularJS filter displays records that don't contain the string from the filter textbox

Tags: angularjs, filter

I'm using angularJS filter to filter data in a grid view. Here is my .cshtml code:

```
<quickfilter search-model="search"></quickfilter>
<table class="grid">
<thead>
    <tr>        
        <th>State Code</th>
        <th>Company ID</th>
        <th>Work Comp Code</th>
        <th>Rate</th>               
    </tr>
</thead>
<tr ng-repeat="m in models | filter:search ">
   <td>
        <td><span ng-bind="m.StateCode"></span></td>
        <td><span ng-bind="m.CompanyId"></span></td>
        <td><span ng-bind="m.WorkCompCd"></span></td>
        <td><span ng-bind="m.Rate"></span></td>         
    </tr>
</table>
```

The filter does filter data based, but some records that don't contain the string that I enter in the filter textbox are also shown. For example, if I enter "111", it shows the records that contain that, plus a couple records that do not. Has anybody have this problem before? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the string "111" is not present an _any_ of the properties of `m`?

Comment: @DavinTryon - Yes, for example, it displays a record with this data: 'NJ', '207', '8292', '6.099'. There are two other columns in the database, date modified and isactive, non of them contain that string.

Comment: And those are the only 4 properties of `m`?

Comment: @DavinTryon - You were right, there was a double that I didn't use that contained '111' in several records. I fixed that. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the filter is filtering over *all* properties of the model `m`, if *any* properties contain the test "111", then it will filter out the entire model.

This is because you are applying the filter to the `ng-repeat`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="m in models | filter:search ">
```

So, any property of `m` will be affected by the filter.